# Does there exist a c/c++ Code Formatter to align comments that occur on same line as code?

Tags: c++, c, comments, formatter

Does there exist a c/c++ code beautifier that will align comments that occur on the same line as the code, i.e.

from this:

```
for(i = 0;i < 10; i++)   /* a for loop */
{
     printf("Hello\n");       /* print hello */
}
```

to this:

```
for(i = 0;i < 10; i++)        /* a for loop */
{
     printf("Hello\n");       /* print hello */
}
```

Comment: Though there is nothing wrong with inline comments, I typically put my comments before the method/loop/etc; then I don't have this problem. When I do use inline comments, the tab key becomes my friend.

Comment: No, not that I am aware of...except for the Tab-key, obviously. I don't know how that would be possible either, because every line of code has a different length. Would all comments begin at the farthest right of a any codeline in that document? I don't think that would help the readability much.

Comment: How would it know against what reference point to align the comments? The position of the first comment? The length of the longest line in the block?

Comment: @Component10 brings the most important point. Unless you have a precise definition of what you want, you might not get it. How would an automated tool determine what column should the comments be in? What if, given an arbitrary decision some comments fall off the right margin (if you have one in your coding style), what if shifting all comments in the block to the left to avoid that would move some over actual code? What constitutes a block (i.e. should comment in line 1 be aligned with comment in line 10, 100, 1000?)

Comment: @Component10 Such programs always have 100's of options or configuration parameters to answer such questions:-).  (Note that it wouldn't be hard to write, either.  A couple of lines of Python should do the trick.)

Comment: @Bob2Chiv: I am working with legacy code, so I don't have an option of where I want to put the comment.

Comment: @Component10:  It could be specified by the user, i.e align comments after longest line or only align comments after column such and such.

Comment: @Component10: I would like to have that couple of lines of python code :)

Answer (score 4):

[GNU Iindent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) can do it

```
$ cat 11991497.c
for(i=0;i<10;i++)              /* a for loop */
{
    printf("Hello\n");    /* print hello */
}
$ indent -npro -nut < 11991497.c
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)        /* a for loop */
  {
    printf ("Hello\n");         /* print hello */
  }
```

The `-npro` command-line parameter instruct indent to not read configuration files. The `-nut` parameter is to use spaces rather than tabs.

The default behaviour is for indent to use "GNU style".

It can be configured to give a style more like (or even maybe exactly like) in your example.

Comment: I just tried it on a more complicated example and it doesn't work.  I wonder why it works for my simple example?

Comment: If you use vim, try `gg=G` (that's `gg`: go to the begining; `=` indent to; `G` the end). I use `indent` very very often and it basically works with every I throw at it (I only throw C89 at it -- it may have problems with C99 or extensions).

Comment: pmg: I'm not using vim.  What does it mean to go to the begining and indent to the end?  What does it exactly do?

Comment: Never mind: I tested it just now and it doesn't align comments; it basically only indents and unindents according to braces.

Comment: Should I just go to command mode and enter gg=G?  I tried that and it indented the printf statement (using a tab).  The comments were not aligned.

Comment: Didregard my last comment. I posted at the same time you did.

Answer (score 2):

If your using VS2010 there is an extension called [Code Alignment](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7179e851-a263-44b7-a177-1d31e33c84fd/)  that will allow you to easily align you code based on what you want.

Comment: Is Code Alignment in the express edition.  I working with embeddded code in code composer studio, but I would be willing to give Code Alignment a try.

Comment: It is an Extension that you download through the website.